# How to combine data structure that uses hash and heap

Tags: c, data-structures, heap, hashtable

Lets say we have a garage that fixes cars, in idle situations, it works by FIFO, however there is some situations that it fix the cars by the severity of the damage (In other words, it will start fixing the car with the highest damage rank and not by FIFO)

Now, we have to use two data structures, max heap and linked hash, in order to store the cars, and run other functions.

How do You think we can combine these two data structures in order to reach our goal?
Is the only way to do this, is by using two separated data structures? (one for heap and one for hash). Or is there is another way to combine these two types?

We're new to this type of things, and we will be happy if someone can give us any explanation and directions

Many thanks

Comment: One question: Can't you consider having a single `queue` or `FIFO` if you may, sort it based on damage and pick the top most entry?

Comment: No it's not possible, I must use linked hash and max heap.... also when I insert cars, I do not know If I will be fixing them by FIFO or severity (It will be known later by the functioned used)

Answer (score 1):

You can link a hash map and a heap, although doing so can be kind of tricky. The only advantage it gives you is that you can locate a particular node in the heap quickly rather than having to search the heap.

I can't imagine, though, why you'd use a max heap as your default data structure when a FIFO queue would be a more reasonable choice. As you say, the default is to process things in FIFO order.

With a FIFO queue as your primary data structure, items are removed in the order they're inserted. And if you want to remove an item based on max damage from time to time, you can search the queue to locate the item, and remove it manually. Or, if you can't search the queue, you can repeatedly dequeue and enqueue items until you've found the one you want, and then dequeue/enqueue the rest until you've put the queue back in order.

If you use a max heap keyed on insertion time, then your key comparison has to be backwards in order to accommodate the FIFO behavior. You could key on damage, but then your default FIFO behavior would require searching the heap to find items in FIFO order.

In short, it's possible to do what you're asking, but it doesn't make a lot of sense.